# What is wrong in the following thread implementation(beginner)?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os, time, sys, threading, pickle
import _thread
def do_more(selected_site):
  print(selected_site)

def do(threadName, selected_site):
  do_more(selected_site);
  print(f'{threadName} ended');

def main(argv):
  selected_site = "abc.com"
  _thread.start_new_thread( do, ("Thread-1", selected_site ) )
  _thread.start_new_thread( do, ("Thread-2", selected_site ) )

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv[1:])
```

either `Thread-1 ended` or `Thread-2 ended` is being but not both and secondly nothing in do_more() is getting printed

Comment: You're not waiting for either thread to finish, so `main` exits as soon as the threads are started.

Comment: though I have to ask -- why are you using `_thread` instead of `threading`?

Comment: following this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: also in that tutorial: "The thread module has been "deprecated" for quite a long time. Users are encouraged to use the threading module instead."